# Reuse host for Integration testing in a .NET 8 console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 console app that I configure the following way:

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<Main>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
{
    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
});

using var host = builder.Build();

await host.Services.GetRequiredService<Main>().ExecuteAsync();
```

How can I reuse this host in my integration test project, but override parts of the service configuration, update environment name etc? What I'm after is what Microsoft does in [their integration tests for web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram>: WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((container, options) =>
            {
                var connection = container.GetRequiredService<DbConnection>();
                options.UseSqlite(connection);
            });
        });

        builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
    }
}
```

Pseudo code of what I'm after:

```
public class MyTest
{
    private IHost _host;

    void Setup()
    {
        _host = CreateHost();
        _host.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IFooService, MockService>();
        });
        _host.UseEnvironment("Test");
    }

    void TearDown()
    {
        _host.Dispose();
    }

    public async Task Test()
    {
        var sender = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<ISender>();
        var result = await sender.Send(new Query());

        Assert.Equal(1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass an Action to the `Setup()`

Answer (score 2):

For a console application, you'll have to do the groundworks yourself.

That starts with making the `Program` class that gets auto generated by [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) accessible to the test project; by default that auto generated one is `internal`.

One way to do so is via the "`public partial class` approach" mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory) you pointed to.
Alternatively, you can also switch completely to the [old program style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style).

Define a public (static) partial class `Program` in your `Program.cs` file, having a public static method - e.g. `CreateApplicationBuilder` - that sets up the `HostApplicationBuilder`.
You use this method in both the actual console application and in the test.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
using var host = builder.Build();
await host.Services.GetRequiredService<Main>().ExecuteAsync();


public static partial class Program
{
    public static HostApplicationBuilder CreateApplicationBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddTransient<IFooService, FooService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<Main>();
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();        
        // More ...
    
        return builder;
    }
}
```

In the setup method of your test you call that `CreateApplicationBuilder` method on `Program` to access the builder and to make customizations like replacing services that are already registered and adjusting the environment.

**MyTest.cs**

```
public void Setup()
{
    var builder = Program.CreateApplicationBuilder(Array.Empty<string>());
    builder.Services
        .RemoveAll<IFooService>()
        .AddTransient<IFooService, MockFooService>();
    // More ...

    builder.Environment.EnvironmentName = "Test";

    _host = builder.Build();
}
```

---

How the initial setup and cleanup needs to be done, depends on the testing framework you use.

xUnit has e.g. the concept of various [fixtures](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context).
A class fixture approach, where the fixture (and thereby also the `IHost`) is being shared with all test methods in the same test class (here: `MyTest`), can look like below.

```
public class ApplicationHostBuilderFixture : IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationHostBuilderFixture() 
    {
        var builder = Program.CreateApplicationBuilder(Array.Empty<string>());
        builder.Services
            .RemoveAll<IFooService>()
            .AddTransient<IFooService, MockFooService>();
        // More ...
        builder.Environment.EnvironmentName = "Test";
        Host = builder.Build();
    }

    public IHost Host { get; }

    public void Dispose() => Host.Dispose();
}

public class MyTest : IClassFixture<ApplicationHostBuilderFixture>
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public MyTest(ApplicationHostBuilderFixture fixture)
        => _host = fixture.Host;

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var sender = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<ISender>();
        var result = await sender.Send(new Query());
        Assert.Equal(1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `InternalsVisibleTo`

Comment: @Pieterjan Do you mean that the `partial class Program` definition is not necessary? Without that one, my `CreateApplicationBuilder` gets compiled as a local function, since you can't have access modifiers on methods in a top level statements approach; so that method would not be accessible from the test project.

Comment: No, you wrote "make internal statements public" but that's not really necessary if you use `InternalsVisibleTo` instead. I agree with everything else

Comment: Fair. The combination of `InternalsVisibleTo` and `internal static partial class Program` with the method definition as `internal static HostApplicationBuilder CreateApplicationBuilder(string[] args)` will indeed also work ... it's a choice/preference. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you can create a custom host factory for your tests

with this factory you can create a new host for your tests

```
public class CustomHostFactory<TProgram> : IDisposable where TProgram : class
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public CustomHostFactory()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<Main>();
                services.AddHttpClient();
                services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(TProgram).Assembly);
                });
            });

        _host = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureTestServices(Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        configureServices(serviceCollection);

        foreach (var service in serviceCollection)
        {
            _host.Services.AddSingleton(service.ServiceType, _ => service.ImplementationInstance);
        }
    }

    public void UseEnvironment(string environmentName)
    {
        _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>().EnvironmentName = environmentName;
    }

    public IHost GetHost()
    {
        return _host;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and if you wanna use it, this is an example for it

```
public class MyTest : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CustomHostFactory<Program> _factory;
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public MyTest()
    {
        _factory = new CustomHostFactory<Program>();
        _factory.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IFooService, MockService>();
        });
        _factory.UseEnvironment("Test");

        _host = _factory.GetHost();
    }

    public async Task Test()
    {
        var sender = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<ISender>();
        var result = await sender.Send(new Query());

        Assert.Equal(1, result);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _factory.Dispose();
    }
}
```